# React adding different padding values to different sides with the "padding" property

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to add different padding values to different sides on React? I know the `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` etc. properties but I'm trying to find a way to add them with a single line just like in CSS such as:

```
padding: "10px 7px 10px 7px"
```

Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `padding` [should work fine](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#padding). However, you may also use [paddingVertical](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#paddingvertical) and [paddingHorizontal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#paddinghorizontal) to set padding top to bottom and left to right correspondingly.

All of the following give you the same result:

```
style={{padding: '10px 7px 10px 7px'}}
style={{padding: '10px 7px'}}
style={{paddingVertical: '10px', paddingHorizontal: '7px'}}
```

Comment: actually I couldn't make that work on React Native but if they are different I should change my question title. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes they are different @batatop , You need to use paddingHorizontal if you need padding on both left and right, and paddingVertical if you need padding on both the top and bottom. You can use paddingLeft, paddingRight, paddingTop and paddingBottom, if you need to change them individually on React Native